# Proving two relations are the same with set difference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

I'd just like to know where to start with this problem, where $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations on non-empty set $A$, and suppose that $A-R = A-S$. I am looking to show that equivalence relations $R = S$.

If I say, let an example pair be an element of $A - R$. But with the exclusion of the set, how would you then make the steps to say that $R$ = $S$? Would it involve arbitrating something being equal to what's not removed?

Comment: If $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations on $A$, they are subsets of $A\times A$, not of $A$.

Comment: Are R and S discrete relations that have to do with some larger set A? Or am I misunderstanding something about the terminology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, equivalence relations are subsets of the cartesian product of the set, since they are formed via pairing elements with another elements. Then your statement has to be proven from $A\times A\setminus R=A\times A\setminus S$.

The statement is true, but not because $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations, it is true because you're taking the set difference from the total set. What I mean is: If $X$ is a set and $A,B\subset X$ are subsets, then $A=B\Leftrightarrow X\setminus A=X\setminus B$. Since $X\setminus A$ is the complement of $A$ in $X$, let's denote it by $A^\mathsf c$ (same for $B$), this is the same as saying that $(A^\mathsf c)^\mathsf c=A$.

The $\Rightarrow$ part is obvious. Let's see the $\Leftarrow$ part: $x\in A\Leftrightarrow x\notin X\setminus A\Leftrightarrow^\text{by hypothesis} x\notin X\setminus B\Leftrightarrow x\in B$, so $A=B$.

Comment: I'll probably say that it doesn't look as intuitive for me to see it just yet. I understand the former part, but are you saying that it would be more prudent for me to convert $X - A = X - B$ to $A^c = B^c$, then I can double negate those sides and that would be it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If $X$ is the total set and $A$ is a subset, then $A^\mathsf c$ is $X-A$ by definition. If you already know $(A^\mathsf c)^\mathsf c=A$ then from the hypothesis $X-A=X-B$, which is the same as $A^\mathsf c=B^\mathsf c$, we can take the complement on both sides, which gives $A=B$.

Comment: Nah yeah, your comment provided the clarification I wanted. Thank you.